# Как отсортировать список кортежей?

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка

Есть список кортежей

`lst = [[(3, 'How are you', 2)], (2, 'hi', 1, '@testinformer1bot'), (3, 'hrllo', 2, '@testinformer1bot')]`

Нужно его отсортировать по первому элементу, не могу понять как это сделать.

```
def el0(v):
    return v[0][0]
self.__chats_raw.sort(key=el0)
```

Получаю: `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: У вас неравномерная структура: первый элемент - это список из одного кортежа, а два другие - просто кортежи. То есть, в первом случае вы можете взять нулевой элемент нулевого кортежа, а в двух других вы пытаетесь взять нулевой элемент первого числа в коретеже

Comment: Спасибо! все заработало